# How does emacs select windows to display anything?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

The problem is, that I spent some time to open a view files, and display them next to each other on screen. I invested some time to balance the window sizes so they suit their content. And each window has some content that I need and don't want to search for again.

Now I do something in emacs. `M-x command-<tab>` for autocomplete:

- emacs rolls a dice
- on an even number emacs overrides an existing window with the possible auto completions. To select the window that needs to get rid of it's content, the dice is rolled again
- on an uneven number emacs splits an existing window and shows it's content there. The selection of which window to split, and weather to split it vertically or horizontally, the dice is rolled again.

Of course I am exaggerating here and this is not the true behavior, but it is how I feel emacs behaves. Is there any documentation that I can study so I can predict better how emacs behaves? I mean it's not just for autocompletion, it is also for commands that need to print something, or when I open files.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to customize any library that you use on a daily basis (e.g., auto-complete) and become familiar with `window.el`.  You can create new functions or entirely new libraries that display buffers in any manner you desire, including dedicated frames for certain buffers and associating certain buffers with select frames.  Many people aren't interested in taking complete control, and they just add a few entries to the `display-buffer-alist`.  There are popular libraries to help control the behavior of window display, which people like because it seems less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be complicated, as there's a lot of flexibility about this.

Honestly, I would just start reading the manual here, and follow the cross references:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Window Choice` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Is it ok, if I don't like this "flexibility"? But thanks for your information I will read it.

Comment: It's absolutely OK not to like it, and par for the course with a lot of Emacs behaviour. I think most people don't like Emacs as-is--that's why folks customize it into something they do like.

Answer (score 0):

For specifically suppressing the completions window, you could try [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle), which is available in Melpa.

```
(require 'shackle)
(setq shackle-rules '((completion-list-mode :ignore t)))
(shackle-mode 1)
```

It takes some work to make commands that manipulate the window layout do what you want, and there are a bunch of edge cases.  I've gone from fighting it to trying to be zen about it.  I just let Emacs do its thing and accept it for the most part, and use shackle or some other workaround for the window changes that I find extra annoying.